# How do I set up a proxy server behind a proxy server?

Tags: php, proxy, xampp, http-proxy, proxy-server

I'm running XAMPP on Windows and know that I could set up a proxy server by adding a few lines in httpd.conf and httpd-proxy.conf, but I wonder if there's a way to set up a proxy server that runs behind another proxy server, since my ISP cache files from some websites and I usually don't get the up-to-date data.

Comment: If you like proxies you can put proxies behind your proxies so you can [proxy while you proxy](http://ic.f.tsatic-cdn.net/1310/635_340/2a7a0_1310235.jpg). It's unclear what this has to do with your ISP, caching, or a practical answer though.

Comment: you see when an ISP cache files, when I download the current version of Skype from its official website, I don't get the current version, I get the version they cached, say, a week ago.

Comment: That's a pretty awful cache and ISP, my condolences. Still not sure what this has to do with proxied proxies.

Comment: `ProxyRemote` directive - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyremote